# (C++) Разделить строку на несколько слов

Tags: c++

Как возможно реализовать разделение строки без использования стандартных библиотек C++?

Вот пример:
Строка: test1:test2:test3

*Разделяем*

Строка1: test1

Строка2: test2

Строка3: test3

Comment: Но ведь класс строки доступен из стандартной библиотеки?? Если без его использования, то это уже будет просто Си.

Comment: Почему люди учат С++ и stl им нельзя... что они делали при изучению СИ????? Что у Вас за преподы.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если нельзя stl то пишите на C

Для разделения строки есть strtok отдайте ему строку и сепоратор)))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct
{
    char* _str;
    int _size;
} c_string;


c_string GetCharBuf(int size)
{
    char* tmp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (long unsigned int)size);
    if (tmp)
    {
        memset(tmp, size, ' ');
    }

    c_string c_str;
    c_str._str = tmp;
    c_str._size = size;

    return c_str;
}


int main()
{
    int buff_size = 1024;
    c_string c_str = GetCharBuf(buff_size);
    if (!c_str._str)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Enter a string : ");

    fgets(c_str._str, c_str._size, stdin);

    c_string* str_arr = NULL;
    int arr_size = 0;
    int i = 0;

    char* sprt = ",. ;:\t\n";
    char* tmp_word = strtok(c_str._str, sprt);
    while (tmp_word != NULL)
    {
        ++arr_size;
        str_arr = (c_string*)realloc(str_arr, sizeof(c_string) * (long unsigned int)arr_size);
        str_arr[i]._str = tmp_word;
        str_arr[i]._size = (int)strlen(tmp_word);
        ++i;

        tmp_word = strtok(NULL, sprt);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; ++i)
    {
        printf("str : {%s}, size : {%d}\n", str_arr[i]._str, str_arr[i]._size);
    }

    if (str_arr)
    {
        free(str_arr);
    }

    free(c_str._str);

    return 0;
}
```